# How to have feature branches under Gerrit branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, gerrit, repo

I have a repo with **master** branch, under that we have a **develop** branch. Multiple developers working on different features, so i wanted to have different feature branches from develop, at later point the feature branches can be merged into develop and develop into master at final point.

Is it possible to have sub branch from develop in Gerrit. If so i want to know how can we commit or push or merge these feature branches into develop branch in gerrit.

Eg:

```
Master
  --develop
    --feature1
    --feature2
    --feature3
```

this can be done simply in Git, but Gerrit seems to be a bit different.

Any help is appreciated.;

Comment: What problems have you encountered when creating feature branches in Gerrit?

Comment: @ElpieKay I haven' tried creating the feature branches from develop, just before doing it, as gerrit seems to be different from git just wanted to know it is possible to have it in that way.